# Child dedication can be a Reason for visiting visa petition for USA

Tags: usa, standard-visitor-visas

My sister has filed immigration visa petition for me in USA. Now I want to visit my son and family in USA along with my spouse on a visiting visa. But the Consular officer has rejected my application under section 214 (b). While applying again, can we show the reason of our grandson's dedication as a valid reason.

Comment: You can state whatever reason you like for visiting. By ‘valid reason’ do you mean ‘will it be accepted and my visa approved’? No-one can answer that, unfortunately.

Comment: 214(b) refusals are generally about failure to overcome presumed immigrant intent. This is not about your reason for visiting the US, but about the reasons you have to leave.

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan 214(b) refusals are explicitly and only about the failure to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent, because that's what 214(b) is about.